# Crashed: AVAudioSession Notify Thread EXC_BREAKPOINT in IOS 12 and 13

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, avaudiosession

I am getting EXC_BREAKPOINT crash that occurs in the AVAudioSession Notify Thread. its happends in IOS 12 and 13 only, How to handle this?

Please have a look at crashlytics logs for more info from Firebase .

```
Crashed: AVAudioSession Notify Thread
    0  WebKit                          0x18a6b4430 WTFCrashWithInfo(int, char const*, char const*, int) + 20
    1  WebKit                          0x18a934484 WebKit::CallbackMap::put(WTF::Ref<WebKit::CallbackBase, WTF::DumbPtrTraits<WebKit::CallbackBase> >&&) + 312
    2  WebKit                          0x18a92681c WebKit::CallbackID WebKit::CallbackMap::put<API::SerializedScriptValue*, WTF::Optional<WebCore::ExceptionDetails>, WebKit::CallbackBase::Error>(WTF::Function<void (API::SerializedScriptValue*, WTF::Optional<WebCore::ExceptionDetails>, WebKit::CallbackBase::Error)>&&, WTF::Variant<std::nullptr_t, WTF::UniqueRef<WebKit::ProcessThrottler::Activity<(WebKit::ProcessThrottler::ActivityType)0> >, WTF::UniqueRef<WebKit::ProcessThrottler::Activity<(WebKit::ProcessThrottler::ActivityType)1> > >&&) + 112
    3  WebKit                          0x18a9266a4 WebKit::WebPageProxy::runJavaScriptInMainFrameScriptWorld(WebCore::RunJavaScriptParameters&&, WTF::Optional<WTF::String> const&, WTF::Function<void (API::SerializedScriptValue*, WTF::Optional<WebCore::ExceptionDetails>, WebKit::CallbackBase::Error)>&&) + 176
    4  WebKit                          0x18a9265bc WebKit::WebPageProxy::runJavaScriptInMainFrame(WebCore::RunJavaScriptParameters&&, WTF::Function<void (API::SerializedScriptValue*, WTF::Optional<WebCore::ExceptionDetails>, WebKit::CallbackBase::Error)>&&) + 32
    5  WebKit                          0x18a879680 -[WKWebView _evaluateJavaScript:asAsyncFunction:withArguments:forceUserGesture:completionHandler:] + 548
    6  VIsualVoiceMail Production      0x1020e8d50 ViewController.audioRouteChanged() + 4363767120 (<compiler-generated>:4363767120)
    7  VIsualVoiceMail Production      0x1020e9538 @objc ViewController.audioRouteChanged() + 4363769144 (<compiler-generated>:4363769144)
    8  CoreFoundation                  0x1830d0504 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
    9  CoreFoundation                  0x1830d054c ___CFXRegistrationPost1_block_invoke + 64
    10 CoreFoundation                  0x1830cf8a4 _CFXRegistrationPost1 + 368
    11 CoreFoundation                  0x1830cf57c ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 88
    12 CoreFoundation                  0x18304c2d4 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1412
    13 CoreFoundation                  0x1830ceedc _CFXNotificationPost + 1236
    14 Foundation                      0x18343c974 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 60
    15 AVFAudio                        0x18feec104 avfaudio::AVAudioSessionPropertyListener(void*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void const*) + 2640
    16 AudioToolbox                    0x18e3b5484 AudioSessionPropertyListeners::CallPropertyListeners(unsigned int, unsigned int, void const*) + 596
    17 AudioToolbox                    0x18e4098b0 HandleCFPropertyListChange(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned char*, unsigned int) + 696
    18 AudioToolbox                    0x18e40f468 HandleAudioSessionCFTypePropertyChangedMessage(unsigned int, unsigned int, void*, unsigned int) + 328
    19 AudioToolbox                    0x18e40eb80 ProcessDeferredMessage(unsigned int, __CFData const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 1620
    20 AudioToolbox                    0x18e40e17c ASCallbackReceiver_AudioSessionPingMessage + 632
    21 AudioToolbox                    0x18e47c398 _XAudioSessionPingMessage + 44
    22 libAudioToolboxUtility.dylib    0x18e50f430 mshMIGPerform + 264
    23 CoreFoundation                  0x1830f3174 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
    24 CoreFoundation                  0x1830f2880 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 444
    25 CoreFoundation                  0x1830ed634 __CFRunLoopRun + 1888
    26 CoreFoundation                  0x1830ecba8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
    27 AVFAudio                        0x18fec3a2c GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 156
    28 AVFAudio                        0x18ff147a0 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 204
    29 libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x182e8ad98 _pthread_start + 156
    30 libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x182e8e74c thread_start + 8
```